# Is there a way to search for songs using the Spotify API with a non-premium account but not play them?

Tags: android, spotify

I am looking into developing an Android app which used the Spotify API. From their tutorial found here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/, you must sign in as a premium user in order to play the song. I looked more into how this worked, and it involves setting the scope using this line:

```
builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming"});
```

The "streaming" scope requires a premium account. I searched through this page which has all of the scopes: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/ and I was wondering which one would be used if I want to JUST search for a song and not play it. Is this possible to do with a free account?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just remove streaming scope

Comment: Do you know how to play songs without premium membership?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the page you linked:

> If no scope is specified, access is permitted only to publicly available information: that is, only information normally visible to normal logged-in users of the Spotify desktop, web, and mobile clients (e.g. public playlists).

After removing the "streaming" scope, I believe you be able to search for songs. That being said, the [Spotify Web API endpoints for search](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) say that you don't need authentication to search. You can try out an [unofficial Spotify web API wrapper](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) to make this a bit easier.

Comment: I haven't checked it out yet but that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!